# Android Studio won't export Jar

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, plugins, jar

i create a new android studio project , add new Module

and i get unity plugin by this path
"D:\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Variations\mono\Release\Classes"

i add classes.jar to mylibrary>libs
right click "classes.jar" and add library

edit mylibrary>build.gradle ,like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/classes.jar')
}
task deleteOldJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'release/AndroidPlugin.jar'
}
task exportJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('release/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'AndroidPlugin.jar')
}

exportJar.dependsOn(deleteOldJar, build)
```

and add a java

```
package com.example.mylibrary;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;
public class GetUrl extends UnityPlayerActivity {
    public static void Show(final String title, final String content)
    {
        UnityPlayer.currentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UnityPlayer.currentActivity);
                builder.setTitle(title).setMessage(content).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                builder.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

after Refresh , i open grable menu , double click createJar , but no any file spawn

I am looking for a lot of tutorials and follow, try a few hours, almost the same steps, but still no results, do you have any ideas?
D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete the code:

```
task deleteOldJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'release/AndroidPlugin.jar'
}
task exportJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('release/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'AndroidPlugin.jar')
}

exportJar.dependsOn(deleteOldJar, build)
```

And just double-click the build function under your mylibrary gradle actions. Then get the newly minted `mylibrary-debug.aar` file from `/YourAndroidProject/mylibrary/build/outputs/aar/mylibrary-debug.aar` and drag it into your `Plugins/Android` folder in your unity project.

Comment: I finally successfully called AAR after a long time of trial, thanks